# All Docker container statuses?

Tags: docker

The list of Docker statuses is [here](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/19790c46dc7fbd489bbd4ccd6f138663312e7579/api/types/types.go#L183). However, when I list docker containers using the API, the statuses are shown in 'natural' sentences; e.g.:

- `Exited (0) NN seconds ago`
- `Up NN days`
- and so on...

I couldn't find the definitive list of all string outputs for all the statuses. In other words, I want to parse docker API status strings.

What are all the possible outputs of the Docker API for container statuses?

Here is the [api](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.21/#list-containers) Im talking about.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The logic by which the status summary is generated can be found in the [Docker source code, in the file `container/states.go`, l. 41ff.](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/b44b5bbc8ba48f50343602a21e7d44c017c1e23d/container/state.go#L41). Basically, you'll get one of the following:

- Up 1 day (paused)
- Restarting (123) 1 day ago
- Up 1 day
- Removal in Progress
- Dead
- Created
- Exited (123) 1 day ago
- (empty string)

In order to get a machine-readable output, I'd suggest using the [`/containers/:id/json` endpoint](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.21/#inspect-a-container), which will return a data structure like the following:

```
"State": {
    "Dead": false, 
    "Error": "", 
    "ExitCode": 0, 
    "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z", 
    "OOMKilled": false, 
    "Paused": false, 
    "Pid": 2593, 
    "Restarting": false, 
    "Running": true, 
    "StartedAt": "2015-12-26T19:22:38.616937722Z", 
    "Status": "running"
}
```

Comment: What I want to know is what are the valid values for `"Status"` in that JSON output. I've only ever seen `"running"` but what else can it be?

Answer (score 5):

From their [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/#filtering)

> One of created, restarting, running, removing, paused, exited, or dead

In my experience, immediately on starting a container, it's `created`, then shortly after it's `running`, then when it exits with a zero *or* non-zero exit code, it's `exited`.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used the remote API, but I'm pretty sure what you actually want to do is get the ID of all containers, then get the `State` information for each container using `/containers/(id)/json`:

```
...
  "State": {
        "Error": "",
        "ExitCode": 9,
        "FinishedAt": "2015-01-06T15:47:32.080254511Z",
        "OOMKilled": false,
        "Paused": false,
        "Pid": 0,
        "Restarting": false,
        "Running": true,
        "StartedAt": "2015-01-06T15:47:32.072697474Z",
        "Status": "running"
    },
...
```

That way you get the same data in a much more standard form.