# List of all reasons for Container States in kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Is it possible to have a list of all reasons for the various [container states](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#container-states) mentioned in kubernetes. So list of reasons for the state `Waiting`, `Running` and `Terminated`. For example, a state of `Waiting` can have a Reason of `ErrImagePull` or `CrashLoopBackOff`.

Please note that this is different from the list of events given in the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51423080/3079474). I have also looked at the docker container statuses mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34472201/all-docker-container-statuses) but they don't seem to cover all the possibilities.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are looking for is this [document](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/blob/master/docs/pod-metrics.md) on official Kubernetes repository, which describes list of reasons for each of container status. For `Waiting` container status it is possible to get one of following reason:

- ContainerCreating,
- CrashLoopBackOff,
- ErrImagePull,
- ImagePullBackOff,
- CreateContainerConfigError,
- InvalidImageName,
- CreateContainerError.

For `Terminated` container status there are different list of reasons:

- OOMKilled,
- Error,
- Completed,
- ContainerCannotRun,
- DeadlineExceeded

And so on, I hope it will helps you.